# Mysql LIKE no filtra datos PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema en PHP al enviar datos para filtrar si lo realizo con el "=" no hay problema me trae los registros pero si intento realizarlo con LIKE , no me devuelve nada.

Es el tm_profesor_dni.

```
public function buscar_profesor_dni($dni){   
    $conectar= parent::conexion();
    $dni = $_POST["dni"];
    $sql="SELECT tm_profesor.pro_id, tm_tipo_documento.td_nom, tm_profesor.pro_dni, tm_profesor.pro_apep, tm_profesor.pro_apem,
        tm_profesor.pro_nom, tm_region.reg_cod + tm_profesor.pro_dni AS 'nrocolegi', tm_region.reg_nom, tm_ugel.ug_nom
        FROM tm_profesor
        INNER JOIN tm_region ON tm_profesor.reg_id = tm_region.reg_id
        INNER JOIN tm_ugel ON tm_profesor.ug_id = tm_ugel.ug_id
        INNER JOIN tm_tipo_documento ON tm_profesor.td_id = tm_tipo_documento.td_id
        INNER JOIN tm_sexo ON tm_profesor.sex_id = tm_sexo.sex_id
        WHERE 
        tm_profesor.est='1' AND
        tm_profesor.pro_dni LIKE '%?%'";
    //echo $sql; //Imprime la consulta en consola.
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$dni);
    $sql->execute();
    return $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    //print_r($_POST); //Para ver el Array que se envia  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes intentar agregarle los símbolos % fuera del select y pasarlo directamente como parte de la variable, de este modo:

```
$dni='%' . $dni . '%';

$sql="SELECT tm_profesor.pro_id, tm_tipo_documento.td_nom, tm_profesor.pro_dni, tm_profesor.pro_apep, tm_profesor.pro_apem,
        tm_profesor.pro_nom, tm_region.reg_cod + tm_profesor.pro_dni AS 'nrocolegi', tm_region.reg_nom, tm_ugel.ug_nom
        FROM tm_profesor
        INNER JOIN tm_region ON tm_profesor.reg_id = tm_region.reg_id
        INNER JOIN tm_ugel ON tm_profesor.ug_id = tm_ugel.ug_id
        INNER JOIN tm_tipo_documento ON tm_profesor.td_id = tm_tipo_documento.td_id
        INNER JOIN tm_sexo ON tm_profesor.sex_id = tm_sexo.sex_id
        WHERE 
        tm_profesor.est='1' AND
        tm_profesor.pro_dni LIKE ?";

       $sql->bindValue(1,$dni);
```

o también puedes hacerlo de este modo:

```
$sql="SELECT tm_profesor.pro_id, tm_tipo_documento.td_nom, tm_profesor.pro_dni, tm_profesor.pro_apep, tm_profesor.pro_apem,
            tm_profesor.pro_nom, tm_region.reg_cod + tm_profesor.pro_dni AS 'nrocolegi', tm_region.reg_nom, tm_ugel.ug_nom
            FROM tm_profesor
            INNER JOIN tm_region ON tm_profesor.reg_id = tm_region.reg_id
            INNER JOIN tm_ugel ON tm_profesor.ug_id = tm_ugel.ug_id
            INNER JOIN tm_tipo_documento ON tm_profesor.td_id = tm_tipo_documento.td_id
            INNER JOIN tm_sexo ON tm_profesor.sex_id = tm_sexo.sex_id
            WHERE 
            tm_profesor.est='1' AND
            tm_profesor.pro_dni LIKE ?";

           $sql->bindValue(1,'%' . $dni . '%');
```

yo suelo utilizar PDO de este modo:

```
$dni='%' . $dni . '%';

$sql="SELECT tm_profesor.pro_id, tm_tipo_documento.td_nom, tm_profesor.pro_dni, tm_profesor.pro_apep, tm_profesor.pro_apem,
                tm_profesor.pro_nom, tm_region.reg_cod + tm_profesor.pro_dni AS 'nrocolegi', tm_region.reg_nom, tm_ugel.ug_nom
                FROM tm_profesor
                INNER JOIN tm_region ON tm_profesor.reg_id = tm_region.reg_id
                INNER JOIN tm_ugel ON tm_profesor.ug_id = tm_ugel.ug_id
                INNER JOIN tm_tipo_documento ON tm_profesor.td_id = tm_tipo_documento.td_id
                INNER JOIN tm_sexo ON tm_profesor.sex_id = tm_sexo.sex_id
                WHERE 
                tm_profesor.est=? AND
                tm_profesor.pro_dni LIKE ?";

$sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
$sql->execute(array(1,$dni));
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, no me devuelve valores , hay algo que tenga que habilitar en el servidor PHP? o mysql?

Comment: Hola, capaz puedas probar si realmente hay algún valor que cumpla con tus fltros del where. Intenta copiar y ejecutar tu mismo select en tu BD.

Comment: Hola gracias , si filtra con el código que me pasaste ya se soluciono pero lo raro es que tengo que colocar 4 caracteres para que pueda filtrar , si coloco menos de eso no me devuelve nada, alguna idea?

Comment: La verdad no sabría el motivo, creo que es cuestión de resultados de la ejecución del query más que de la consulta en sí. Creo que lo deberías probar en la BD y ver si retorna valores con tus filtros. (Cuando puebes en la BD debes agregarles los símbolos %% en tu select)

Comment: Si lo raro es que en el PHPMYADMIN si coloco un valor si devuelve.